# CloudFormation Transform Section stops Rule Assertions from executing

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have the following (contrived) CloudFormation Template, without a Transform Section, which executes the Validation Assertion Rules properly (will show AssertDescription if BlueGreen and Lambda Param values are Equal, and won't let me click "Next" off the first page in the CF Console):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  BlueGreen:
    Type: String
    Default: Yes
    AllowedValues:
      - Yes
      - No

  Lambda:
    Type: String
    Default: No
    AllowedValues:
      - Yes
      - No

Rules:
  ValidateBlueGreenOrLambda:
    Assertions:
      - AssertDescription: "Select BlueGreen or Lambda"
        Assert: !Not [!Equals [!Ref BlueGreen, !Ref Lambda]]

Resources:
  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

However, if I add a Transform Section to the Template, the Rules are not Asserted, and I can continue on in the Console to build the Stack:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: "AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen"

... Rest of Template from above here
```

Does anyone know why adding a Transform Section would stop the Rule Assertions from executing?

Comment: Update: I've submitted a Ticket to AWS Support and they were able to replicate the issue as I had explained, and are working with the Core CloudFormation Team to address. I'll provide more info when I hear back, in the event anyone is interested.

Comment: Update: This has been confirmed to be a bug by the CloudFormation Team, and they are working to address the issue.